# Mysql Error:The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist' when trying to dump tablespaces

Tags: mysql

After I upgraded MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0, I started MySQL again and I got an error:The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist' when trying to dump tablespaces.
I don't understand why this problem occurs. And I want to know how to solve it

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I had the same error when I accidentally downgraded my MySQL version from 8 to 5.7. At the first start the older version broke something so that version 8 was showing the error above. 
In my case I had to enter the docker container where MySQL was running first

```
docker exec -it mysql bash
```

Then I basically followed the steps [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-strategies.html)

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 1;
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

This took some minutes but then everything was working again.

Comment: Thanks. This is a worked for me, also it solved problem with MySQL Workbench, when I couldn't to connect him to mysql-server.

Comment: This happened to me when homebrew on OSX updated Maria and locked me out of my dev dbs.  Thanks!!

Comment: This answer applies to non-docker based MySQL installations as well.

Answer (score 10):

It may occur after some time after you set up your new system.

As a suggested solution, just try on Windows

1) open `cmd.exe` as Administrator

2) run `mysql_upgrade.exe -uyour_user_name -pyour_password`

`mysql_upgrade.exe` can be located at

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

Then run the following to see if the infoschema user has appeared.

```
select user, host from mysql.user;
```

Comment: Worked like a champ on mac os x too? `mysql_upgrade` from terminal.

Comment: `mysql_upgrade -u root` worked for me too in macOS high Sierra

Answer (score 0):

In my case, such error was caused by that I had changed the host of the dba user from % to localhost to strengthen the security.

I used "abcdba" with DDL right to create db schema, and used "abc" with CURD right for the Web service to use the DB. After the change, the read operations were OK but the write operations failed with the error message in the OP.

Flush privilege or restarting the server did not solve the problem. Then I changed to host of the dba user back to %. Then things have become normal again.

Apparently mysql does not like the changes of host of the dba user, and existing databases created by that dba user will have problem if the host of the dba user is changed.

Essentially, changing the host of the dba user is actually removing user abcdba@% and creating a new user abcdba@localhost. Here had come the error message, since abcdba@% and abcdba@localhost are 2 differently fully qualified usernames.